# Converting between MIDI channel volume and real gain

Tags: formula, midi, volume

What is the recommended way of mapping MIDI channel volume to gain?

From here [1]

> It is recommended that a device use the volume value in a logarithmic manner, as specified by the following formula if only the coarse value is used:
>
> 40 log (Volume/127)

To me, this formula looks like an inverse formula. If channel volume is given in dB, then the formula should use `exp` instead of `log`. If volume already is an amplitude, then there should only be `Volume/127`. To clarify, this does not make sense

```
*output_buffer = 40*log(channel_volume/127.0) * (*input_buffer);
```

(Testcase: channel_volume=0 will give infinite gain) The following on the other hand is better (provided that `channel_volume` is the real gain and not the gain in dB):

```
*output_buffer = channel_volume * (*input_buffer)/127.0;
```

[1] [http://www.blitter.com/~russtopia/MIDI/~jglatt/tech/midispec/vol.htm](http://www.blitter.com/%7Erusstopia/MIDI/%7Ejglatt/tech/midispec/vol.htm)

Answer (score 0):

The MIDI specification itself does not specify the volume response.
However, the [General MIDI Level 1 Developer Guidelines](http://www.midi.org/techspecs/gmguide.php) show this formula, because it's actually used by most implementations.

The channel volume is given as a value from 0 to 127.
The result of that formula is measured in dB; you have to convert it into a gain value afterwards:

> gain = 10 ^ (dB / 20)

See the same document for how to handle interactions with the expression controller.

Comment: Which means that this formula should not be used before passing the value as a gain value to a synthesizer. This is what i meant by "inverse"